# Using a html form from another project with Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to use a html form from the internet with Django. However, after watching crazy amount of videos on youtube and reading through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/ , I can't manage to make it work. When I click the submit button, Chrome tells me the "The form has submitted", but nothing else happens. It should log the user in and redirects to the index page.

**registration_form.html**

```
       <div class="panel panel-info mt10 br-n bg-gradient-1 mw500 mauto">
          <form id="contact" method="post" action="{% url 'feed:connection' %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="panel-body text-center p50 text-center">
              <div class="section">
                <p class="text-uppercase text-white ls100 fw700">Username</p>
                {{ form.username.errors }}
                <label for="username" class="field prepend-icon">
                  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" class="gui-input">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="section">
                <p class="text-uppercase text-white ls100 fw700">Password</p>
                {{ form.password.errors }}
                <label for="password" class="field prepend-icon">
                  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" class="gui-input">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-footer clearfix p10 ph15">
                <button type="submit" class="button btn-primary mr10 pull-right text-uppercase text-white ls100 fw700">Sign In</button>
                <!--<label class="switch ib switch-primary pull-left input-align mt10">
                  <input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" checked="">
                  <label for="remember" data-on="YES" data-off="NO"></label> <span>Remember me</span>
                </label> -->
              </div>
              <div class="section text-left pt20 pb10"><a href="#">Forget password?</a>
                <p><span class="text-white">Haven't yet registration? <a href="#">Sign up here</a></span></p>
              </div>
              <div class="section row">
                <div class="col-md-6"><a href="#" class="fw700 ls100 text-white text-uppercase">Facebook</a></div>
                <div class="col-md-6"><a href="#" class="fw700 ls100 text-white text-uppercase">Google +</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import LoginForm


# Pour faire afficher la page index
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'feed/index.html'


# Pour se logger
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'feed/registration_form.html'

    # display blank form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    # process form data
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)

            # cleaned (normalized) data
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.username = username
            user.save()

            # returns User objects if credentials are correct
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:

                if user.is_active:

                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('feed:index')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

app_name = "feed"

urlpatterns = [
    # /feed/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    # /register/
    url(r'^connection/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='connection'),

]
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=8)
```

What is wrong with the code? Thank you for your time.

Comment: The `IndexView` that receives the login form has no code to handle it.

Comment: @KlausD. is right. The action in the form `/` points to **IndexView**. Based on your views, your action should be `/connection/` because thats the one handling form processing.

Comment: Wow thank you guys for your answers, it's extremely fast!

So I changed action="/" to action="/connection/" . However, pyCharm gives me that error: "Cannot resolve directory 'connection' . What should I change?

Comment: Use reverse, that is {% url 'feed:connection' %} as value of action. I am taking that `feed` is the name of the app.

Comment: You are right, feed is the name of the app. So I changed it to action="{% url 'feed:connection' %} , and pyCharm no longer gives me an error. But once again, Chrome tells me "Your form has submitted" and nothing else happens.

I just realized. In PyCharm's console when I runserver, I do not get any POST from when I click on the submit button, even if Chrome tells me it has submitted. What could it be?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: @e4c5 Why did you delete your answer and my comments?

Comment: Because this was beginning to be what we call a rabbit whole answer - where the OP keeps adding new questions as comments